# Jest Unit Test: wrapper.vm.$refs.editForm.validate is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I write test case for form submit, i m getting issue with 1`wrapper.vm.$refs.editForm.validate is not a function`

I am unable to figure out the problem.. please Help me.

`"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0", "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.11.0", "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.11.0", "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.11.0", "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0", "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0", "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29", "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0", "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1", "babel-jest": "^23.6.0"`

==== EditProperty.vue======

```js
<v-form ref="editForm" lazy-validation>
    <v-flex>
      <v-text-field label="Label Text" v-model="labelName" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Label Text is required']"
        
      />
    </v-flex>
</v-form>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      labelName: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      if (this.$refs.editForm.validate()) {
        this.$emit('updateLable', this.labelName)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

======EditProperty.spec.js =====

import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import EditProperty from '@/components/EditProperty.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuetify)
let wrapper
describe('EditProperty.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(EditProperty, {
      localVue,
      data() {
        return {
          labelName: 'Username'
        }
      }
    })
  })
  
  it('should save called correctly', () => {
    wrapper.vm.save()
  })
})
```

expected =>  test should be pass

getting => `wrapper.vm.$refs.editForm.validate is not a function`

When I write test case for form submit, i m getting issue with 1`wrapper.vm.$refs.editForm.validate is not a function`

I am unable to figure out the problem.. please Help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`shallowMount` does not render the child components. I.E. in your case, `v-form` won't be rendered in the test. In fact if you call `html` from your wrapper, you will see a HTML comment in place of the `<edit-form>`.

The rationale behind that vue test utils feature is that, when you're unit testing a component, you test only the logic of such component in isolation, and don't rely on code from other modules.

Now you could manually pass an object as `stub` and provide any test double to allow the `validate()` call, via the `stubs` option:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import EditProperty from '@/components/EditProperty.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuetify)
let wrapper
describe('EditProperty.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const EditFormStub = {
      render: () => {},
      methods: {
        validate: () => true,
      }
    };
    wrapper = shallowMount(EditProperty, {
      localVue,
      stubs: {
        'edit-form': EditFormStub,
      }
      data() {
        return {
          labelName: 'Username'
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('should save called correctly', () => {
    wrapper.vm.save()
  })
})
```

So we are passing a fake `editForm` as a stub, with a fake `validate()` method which always returns true.

Then you can test your component code. For instance, you could test that your label is emitted as `updateLabel` (in your original snippet it was 'updateLable', be wary):

```
    it('should save called correctly', () => {
      wrapper.vm.save();

      expect(wrapper.emitted('updateLabel')[0][0]).toBe(whatever the label should be)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @sergeon for quick response.

But mocking $refs is not working. its throwing same error

Comment: I totally forgot `$refs` is one of the options that vue test utils fails to mock. There is some info about why is that in this github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/271. I updated my answer to provide a solution using `stubs` instead of `mocks`, like the the core maintainer suggests in the github thread.

Answer (score 0):

if you got in a situation where you don't need to stub. You could easily do this:

```js
import { nextTick } from 'vue'

it('test', async () => {
    wrapper.vm.$refs.editForm.validate = jest.fn()
    await nextTick()
})
```